# Find a point on Y axis, so that subtraction of distance from other two is maximal?

Tags: geometry

Given 2 points.
$M(-3; 2)$ and $N(2; 5)$

Find a point $P$ which is on Y axis, so that
$distance(M, P) - distance(N, P)$ is maximal

From condition i assumed that P has coordinates $P(0; y)$

How to solve it?

Comment: Your question is not different from [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483390/what-is-the-coordinate-of-a-point-p-on-the-line-2x-y5-0-such-that-pa-pb) one.

Comment: @G-man I think they are different. According to solution given in problem # 1483390, P should be on the same line as MN and on the y-axis. This gives P= (0, 3.8). and d = PM – PN = 3.5 – 2.33 = 1.17. However, if I let P be at P’(0, –50(roughly)), then, through Geogegra, I have P’N – P’M = 53.77 – 50.83 which is way larger than d.

Comment: @Mick if we assume an equation for Y axis, so x=0, maybe that solution would work.

Comment: x = 0 is a must because P is a point on the y-axis.

Comment: @Mick I just glanced at this question and thought the concept involved was the same.

Comment: @G-man No problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If sum of distances $ MP+ PN$  is constant =$d_1$ , an ellipse can be defined tangent to y-axis only for a particular $d_1$.

Similarly,

If difference of distances  $ MP-PN $  is constant =$d_2$ , a hyperbola can be defined tangent to y-axis only for a particular $d_2$.

Point of tangency / contact has a zero x- coordinate, non-zero y-coordinate.

Numerical results:

Distance difference $ =d_2 \approx  3.18 $, point of tangency $ \approx (0,10).$

[image: Doppler]

Comment: calculation with a brute-force algorithm gives me (0, 11.00) it's close to your answer. But i don't fully understand your solution, can you draw for me to undersand better? Thanks.

Comment: What was the distance difference in your construction?

Comment: dM = 9.487 dN = 6.325 delta = 3.162 y = 11.000

Comment: Seems alright. I read from graph y=10 by eye estimation as you can see it is narrow , 11.0 would be more accurate.

Comment: btw i dont understand this image. Can you write step to step solution with images? Of course if you want.

Comment: After knowing what to expect, I graphed it  on Mma.                        ContourPlot[  {x==0,Sqrt[(x+3)^2 + (y-2)^2] -  Sqrt[(x-2)^2 + (y-5)^2] ==3.18}, {x,-0,10},y,0,15},GridLines->Automatic,AspectRatio->Automatic,ContourStyle->{Thick,Red}]. It avoids cumbersome simplifications.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in assuming the point $P$ will have coordinates $(0, y)$.

**Edit:** My original $d_M$ and $d_N$ were incorrect. They have now been corrected.
The distance from $M$ to $P$, here denoted $d_M =\sqrt{9+(y-2)^2}$, and the distance from $N$ to $P$ can be written $d_N =\sqrt{4+(y-5)^2}$. $d_M - d_N$ can now be written as a function of $y$, and we can find the maximum value by deriving. 
$\frac{d}{dy} \sqrt{9+(y-2)^2} -\sqrt{4+(y-5)^2} =$ 
$\frac{y-2}{\sqrt{9+(y-2)^2}} - \frac{y-5}{\sqrt{4+(y-5)^2}} = 0$
$\frac{(y-2)^2}{9+(y-2)^2} = \frac{(y-5)^2}{4+(y-5)^2}$
$\frac{(y-2)^2+9-9}{(y-2)^2+9} = \frac{(y-5)^2+4-4}{(y-5)^2+4}$
$1-\frac{9}{(y-2)^2+9} = 1-\frac{4}{(y-5)^2+4}$
$\frac{9}{(y-2)^2+9} = \frac{4}{(y-5)^2+4}$
$9(4+(y-5)^2) = 4(9+(y-2)^2)$
$9(y-5)^2 = 4(y-2)^2$
$9y^2 - 90y + 225 = 4y^2 - 16y +16$
$5y^2 - 74y + 209 = 0$
$y = \{11, \frac{38}{10}\}$
Plugging these values back into $d_M - d_N$, we find $y(11) = \sqrt{10}$ and $y(38/10) = \sqrt{34}/5$, so the answer is $P = (0, 11)$

Comment: The distances are  $\sqrt{9+(y-2)^2}$ and $\sqrt{4+(y-5)^2}$.

Comment: when i tried to solve it, your dM and dN is wrong. I got dM = sqrt(3^2 + (y-2)^2) and for dN = sqrt((-2)^2+(y-5)^2).

Comment: Whoops! You guys are right, I'll fix that right away

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT a solution but is an actual plot of the situation.

[image]

Some of the data have been given in my comment above.

When we consider P is on the positive y-axis, say at P’’(0, 10(roughly)), D (= P’’M – P’’N = MX = 3.16 (roughly) as @Narasimham showed) has attained its maximum.

Comment: In my calculation,  $M,P,N$ are not collinear,  graph has not shown the 3 points.

Comment: @Narasimham Yes, I know. I just want to show if M, P, N are collinear, the said difference is NOT a maximum.